# Mounting a folder from other machine in linux

Tags: linux, nfs

I want to mount a folder which is on some other machine to my `linux` server. To do that i am using the following command

```
mount -t nfs 192.xxx.x.xx:/opt/oracle /
```

Which is executing with the following error

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.xxx.x.xx:/opt/oracle
```

Do anyone knows what's going on ??? I am new to linux.

Comment: Linux has directories, not folders. And the message is clear: the server does not accept that mount.

Comment: I know that clear message. i want a solution...

Comment: Linux has directories and folders. 
There is no need to be.... whatever. 
Folder is "the graphical user interface metaphor that is used to represent directory" 

"The distinction can be due to the way a directory is accessed; on Unix systems, /usr/bin/ is usually referred to as a directory when viewed in a command line console, but if accessed through a graphical file manager, users may sometimes call it a folder." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29#Folder_metaphor

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what distro you're using, you simply edit the `/etc/exports` file on the remote machine to export the directories you want, then start your NFS daemon.

Then on the local PC, you mount it using the following command:

```
mount -t nfs {remote_pc_address}:/remote/dir /some/local/dir
```

**Please try with your home directory as per my knowledge you can't dump anything directly on root like that.**

For more reference, find full configuration steps [here](http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-setup-nfs-server-in-linux/).

Comment: The OP might want `mount -t nfs 192.xxx.x.xx:/opt/oracle /opt/oracle` but probably should edit `/etc/exports` on the NFS server and `/etc/fstab` on the local machine.

Comment: Yes i think i missed that part thanks for mentioning @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: @ArnabNandy What if don't have permission for the remote machine to edit 

`/etc/exports `

Comment: @Omkar use sudo